# Como controlar en Trigger si valor nuevo es nulo y obtencion de valores viejos y nuevos del UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger, sql-server-2008

Necesito hacer un trigger que:

Al actualizar mi columna *COD_SESION* a nulo de mi tabla *Usuarios*.

Se haga un *Update* en mi tabla *Evaluaciones* seteando

- *Usuario_bloqueo* = nulo
- *Fecha_bloqueo* = nulo

Donde *Usuario_bloqueo* sea igual al *Id* del usuario del cual estoy cambiando su *COD_SESION*

No conozco la sintaxis de sql server, busque y no encontre algo que me ayude.
Probando llegue a esto pero me da errores de sintaxis

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_BD_UPD_USR on [Usuarios] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.COD_SESSION = NULL
        UPDATE Evalauciones
        SET USUARIO_BLOQUEO = null, FECHA_BLOQUEO = null
        WHERE USUARIO_BLOQUEO = :OLD.USUARIO_BLOQUEO
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el código que has intentado más bien parece de `Oracle`.  Lo que buscas en SQL server podría construirse de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_BD_UPD_USR on [Usuarios]  FOR UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN

    IF update(COD_SESSION) BEGIN

        UPDATE  Evalauciones
            SET USUARIO_BLOQUEO = null, 
                FECHA_BLOQUEO = null
            FROM Evaluaciones E
            INNER JOIN INSERTED I
                ON I.USUARIO_BLOQUEO = E.USUARIO_BLOQUEO
                AND I.COD_SESSION IS NULL
    END
END
```

Comentarios:

- En SQL Server los triggers se ejecutan por BATCH no por fila, por consiguiente siempre hay que tener esto en mente. Cualquier código que implementes pensando que solo se está actualizando una fila es incorrecto.
- Del punto anterior es que el código que te muestro hace una consulta de actualización sobre todas las `Evalauciones` que coincidan con las filas (1 o más) actualizadas de `Usuarios` y dónde el valor nuevo de `COD_SESSION` sea `NULL`
- El `IF update(COD_SESSION)` hace que el código se ejecute solo si se ha actualizado esta columna.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono el trigger, una pregunta. Que significa que el trigger se ejecuta por BATCH no por fila?

Comment: Que si tu `update` actualiza 10 filas, el trigger se ejecuta una sola vez, no 10 veces por cada fila. Saludos